How could I auto fill the value of cities and barangay dropdown menu in a user verification form website that uses behavior subject?
I'm trying to auto fill a dropdown menu of the updated value when going back to the first page. there is a permanent and current address. in the current and permanent address only the coutnry and province show, but the city and barangay is not. but when I click the province value, the city dropdown menu autofill and when I click the city, the barangay dropdown menu autofill.
in the page 2

 goToPersonalInfo() {
    // Updates the form source with the current player profile and navigates to the personal info section of the KYC wizard
    this.userVerificationService.formSource.next(this.playerProfile);
    this.router.navigate(['user-kyc-wizard/personal-info']);
}

clicking back to page 1 personal-info to receive again the profilePlayer data to autofill the form

int the ngOniInit ()
// Subscribe to formSource to receive playerProfile data
  this.userVerificationService.formSource.pipe(takeUntil(this.closed$)).subscribe((playerProfile: PLAYER_PROFILE) => {
    console.log('Player Profile:', playerProfile); // Log the playerProfile object
    // Logic to handle the updated playerProfile here
    this.playerProfile = playerProfile;

    // Log playerAddress to check its structure
    console.log('Player Address:', playerProfile.playerAddress);

    // Prefill the personal info form fields
    this.personalInfoForm.patchValue({
      firstName: playerProfile.firstName,
      middleName: playerProfile.middleName,
      lastName: playerProfile.lastName,
      sourceOfIncome: playerProfile.sourceOfIncome,
      natureOfWork: playerProfile.natureOfWork,
      placeOfBirth: playerProfile.placeOfBirth,
      dateOfBirth: playerProfile.dateOfBirth,
      gender: playerProfile.gender,
      citizenShip: playerProfile.citizenship,
      idType: playerProfile.idType,
      idNumber: playerProfile.idNumber,
      idImageUrl: playerProfile.idImageUrl,
      profileImageUrl: playerProfile.profileImageUrl,
      userId: playerProfile.userId,
    });

    // Prefill permanent address form fields if available
    if (playerProfile.playerAddress[0]) {
      const permanentAddress = playerProfile.playerAddress[0];
      console.log('Permanent Address:', permanentAddress); // Log permanent address object
      this.playerPermanentAddress.patchValue({
        street: permanentAddress.street,
        subdivision: permanentAddress.subdivision,
        barangay: permanentAddress.barangay || '', // Ensure barangay is filled
        city: permanentAddress.city || '', // Ensure city is filled
        province: permanentAddress.province,
        country: permanentAddress.country || 'Philippines',
        isPermanentAddress: true,
      });
    }

    // Apply permanent address to current address if applyToCurrentAddress is true
    if (playerProfile.applyToCurrentAddress) {
      this.applyPermanentAddressToCurrent({ checked: true });
    } else if (playerProfile.playerAddress[1]) {
      // Prefill current address form fields if available and applyToCurrentAddress is false
      const currentAddress = playerProfile.playerAddress[1];
      console.log('Current Address:', currentAddress); // Log current address object
      this.playerCurrentAddress.patchValue({
        street: currentAddress.street,
        subdivision: currentAddress.subdivision,
        barangay: currentAddress.barangay || '', // Ensure barangay is filled
        city: currentAddress.city || '', // Ensure city is filled
        province: currentAddress.province,
        country: currentAddress.country || 'Philippines',
        isPermanentAdd`your text`ress: false,
      });
    }

    // Activate closeUserVerificationModal function
    this.closeUserVerificationModal();
  });
 


I tried to appply the function that in the applyPermanentToCurrent () because it autofill the dropdown menu of city and barangay

applyPermanentAddressToCurrent(event) {
    this.applyToCurrentAddress = event.checked;
    if (this.applyToCurrentAddress == true) {
      this.playerCurrentAddress.get('street').setValidators(null);
      this.playerCurrentAddress.get('subdivision').setValidators(null);
      this.playerCurrentAddress.get('barangay').setValidators(null);
      this.playerCurrentAddress.get('city').setValidators(null);
      this.playerCurrentAddress.get('province').setValidators(null);
      this.playerCurrentAddress.get('country').setValidators(null);
      this.playerCurrentAddress.get('isPermanentAddress').setValidators(null);

      this.playerCurrentAddress
        .get('street')
        .setValue(this.playerPermanentAddress.get('street').value);
      this.playerCurrentAddress
        .get('subdivision')
        .setValue(this.playerPermanentAddress.get('subdivision').value);

      this.userVerificationService
        .getProvince()
        .pipe(
          switchMap((response) => {
            this.provinces = response;

            const filteredProvince = this.provinces.filter(
              (x) =>
                x.provinceName ==
                this.playerPermanentAddress.get('province').value
            );

            this.playerCurrentAddress
              .get('province')
              .setValue(this.playerPermanentAddress.get('province').value);

            this.playerCurrentAddress
              .get('country')
              .setValue(this.playerPermanentAddress.get('country').value);

            this.playerCurrentAddress.disable();

            return this.userVerificationService.getCity(
              filteredProvince[0].provinceCode
            );
          })
        )
        .subscribe({
          next: (response) => {
            this.currentAddressCities = response;

            const filteredCity = this.currentAddressCities.filter(
              (x) => x.cityName == this.playerPermanentAddress.get('city').value
            );

            this.playerCurrentAddress
              .get('city')
              .setValue(this.playerPermanentAddress.get('city').value);

            this.userVerificationService
              .getBarangay(filteredCity[0].cityCode)
              .subscribe({
                next: (response) => {
                  console.log('Get Barangays');
                  this.currentAddressBarangays = response;

                  this.playerCurrentAddress
                    .get('barangay')
                    .setValue(
                      this.playerPermanentAddress.get('barangay').value
                    );
                },
              });
          },
        });
    } else {
      this.playerCurrentAddress.enable();
      this.playerCurrentAddress
        .get('street')
        .setValidators([Validators.required]);
      this.playerCurrentAddress
        .get('subdivision')
        .setValidators([Validators.required]);
      this.playerCurrentAddress
        .get('barangay')
        .setValidators([Validators.required]);
      this.playerCurrentAddress
        .get('city')
        .setValidators([Validators.required]);
      this.playerCurrentAddress
        .get('province')
        .setValidators([Validators.required]);
      this.playerCurrentAddress
        .get('country')
        .setValidators([Validators.required]);
      this.playerCurrentAddress
        .get('isPermanentAddress')
        .setValidators([Validators.required]);

      this.playerCurrentAddress.get('street').setValue(null);
      this.playerCurrentAddress.get('subdivision').setValue(null);
      this.playerCurrentAddress.get('barangay').setValue(null);
      this.playerCurrentAddress.get('city').setValue(null);
      this.playerCurrentAddress.get('province').setValue(null);
    }
    this.playerCurrentAddress.get('street').updateValueAndValidity();
    this.playerCurrentAddress.get('subdivision').updateValueAndValidity();
    this.playerCurrentAddress.get('barangay').updateValueAndValidity();
    this.playerCurrentAddress.get('city').updateValueAndValidity();
    this.playerCurrentAddress.get('province').updateValueAndValidity();
    this.playerCurrentAddress.get('country').updateValueAndValidity();
    this.playerCurrentAddress
      .get('isPermanentAddress')
      .updateValueAndValidity();
    this.playerCurrentAddress.markAllAsTouched();
  }```

